# disable Apache LDAP Auth for API resources

Tags: api, apache, ldap

is it possible to disable Apache LDAP Auth for API resources, so it is still needed for the browser but not for any kind of REST API requests?

Or maybe bypassing it when requests come from specific networks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to work around this is by whitelisting the network in the Apache LDAP Auth from which the API requests are done.